# Generate and print barcode by flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to generate a barcode and finally print the generated barcode. but idk how to print that.

here's code's:

```
  var BarcodeController = TextEditingController();

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var pageHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: pageHeight/4,
              width: pageWidth,
              child: SfBarcodeGenerator(
                value: BarcodeController.text,
                showValue: true,
                textSpacing: pageWidth/20,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: pageWidth/20),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: pageWidth/15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
              ),
              child:  TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                controller: BarcodeController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

i use this package for generate barcode : [syncfusion_flutter_barcodes package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_barcodes)
and now i need to print this barcode on a real paper by a real printer. so is there any package to print? and also how can i print this barcode by that package?

Comment: you can use this library ```barcode: ^2.2.0``` to generate and print barcode easily

Answer (score 0):

You can capture `Widget` contain QR code, save this image to path. Then you print the document using service of the iOS or Android device with this lib [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing):

```
final doc = pw.Document();
final image = await imageFromAssetBundle('assets/image.png');

doc.addPage(pw.Page(
build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(image),
  ); // Center
})); // Page
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => doc.save());
```

Detail about capture widget, see the following instructions

```
static GlobalKey previewContainer = new GlobalKey();

//
RepaintBoundary(
          key: previewContainer,
          child: SfBarcodeGenerator()//
        )

//
Future<String> takeScreenShot() async {
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
  // final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  print(pngBytes);
  String imagePath = join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${timestamp()}.png');
  File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
  // File imgFile = new File('$directory/'+'${timestamp()}.png');
  imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  return imagePath;
}

String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without saving to path? Or would you recommend just deleting it after you save it? I am concerned about permissions for this so ideally, I would prefer to just print the generated QR code without having to save it to the device.